# How to set row value is 'No' if values is not found in SQL table?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have one table name called person.

E.g:

```
  Name       Address
-------------------------------------
  a          India
  b           US
  c           UK
```

I would like to check if particular name is exist or not. If not exists I would like to show as 'No'.

**E.g:**

I tried below query to get result. But 'D' is not found the table. So, I am getting values as empty.

```
select Name, case when Name in ('a','d','e') Then 'Yes' Else 'No' END As Status from person


     Name       Status
 ------------------------------
      a           Yes
```

I need output like as below format:

```
  Name       Status
-------------------------------------
  a           Yes
  b           Yes
  c           Yes
  d           No
  e           No
```

Can you please help me. How to solve this task?

Comment: Hi....anyone please help me or suggest how to solve this.

Comment: Please try to make use of below code, I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Make use of below code:

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(20), Country NVARCHAR(20))
    INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
    ('a','India'),
    ('b','US'),
    ('c','UK')
```

Create a table variable to store the name fields you need to check:

```
    DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(20))
    INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES
    ('a'),
    ('d'),
    ('e')

    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN T.Name IS NULL THEN TE.Name ELSE T.Name END AS Name, 
    CASE WHEN T.Name IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS Staus
    FROM @Table T FULL JOIN @Temp TE
    ON T.Name =TE.Name
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Name  Staus
   a    YES
   b    YES
   c    YES
   d    NO
   e    NO
```

Comment: Lot of thanks. It's working fine. Thanks for your quick support.

Comment: @Dhamo If it helps you to solve your problem, pleas up vote my answer :)

Comment: But If Country not null means it's not working as expect.

Comment: @Dhamo I had modified the query. Please check now.